# How to capture and store the selected values from listbox in Msaccess code

Tags: ms-access

I have the below code used to capture the selected values from listbox in msaccess. All I'm getting is only the index value but not the actual value which is a string value.
eg. if my listbox contains values like XXX,AAA,BBB and if i select XXX the code is fetching the index value of XXX as 0 and using it every where. But my expectation is to capture and store XXX as value.

```
Private Sub Create_Invoice_Click()
On Error GoTo Err_Create_Invoice_Click

Dim xlWorksheetPath As String
Dim dbTable As String
Dim dbTablee As String
Dim BaCode As String
Dim lst As ListBox
Set lst = Me.BA_CD
Dim rowcount As Long
Dim oItem As Variant
Dim iCount As Integer

If lst.ItemsSelected.Count <> 0 Then
For Each oItem In lst.ItemsSelected
If iCount = 0 Then
BaCode = BaCode & lst.ItemData(oItem)
iCount = iCount + 1
Else
BaCode = BaCode & "," & lst.ItemData(oItem)
iCount = iCount + 1
End If
Next oItem
Else
MsgBox "Nothing was selected from the list"
Exit Sub 'Nothing was selected
End If

xlWorksheetPath = "systempath\"

xlWorksheetPath = xlWorksheetPath & BaCode & ".xls"

dbTable = "table1"
dbTablee = "table2"
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tablename:=dbTable, filename:=xlWorksheetPath, hasfieldnames:=True
DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet transfertype:=acExport, spreadsheettype:=acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, tablename:=dbTablee, filename:=xlWorksheetPath, hasfieldnames:=True
MsgBox "Data trasfered successfully"

Exit_Create_Invoice_Click:
Exit Sub

Err_Create_Invoice_Click:
MsgBox Err.Description`enter code here`
Resume Exit_Create_Invoice_Click

End Sub
```

Comment: Have you heard about code indentation ? It's supposed to make the code readable.

Answer (score 1):

In the listbox, column 0 should be the ID of the selected value, and is the value being selected with `lst.ItemData(oItem)`.

Column 1 would be the first visible value in the list.

Try changing `lst.ItemData(oItem)`   to   `lst.Column(1, oItem)`